# object api name on where sharing rules of account object gets stored

Tags: sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I'm just curious to know that when I create a sharing rule for account via sharing settings. I want to know on which object the sharing rule record is getting stored when I create the sharing rule for account object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing rules are usually present in the metadata .So [metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sharingrules.htm) will have definitions of your rule .

Salesforce recommends to use this for all updates to sharing rules .

However under the hood salesforce has tables named as "OwnerSharingRules" for each object where you have these sharing rules .

> **However to enable these object for your org you will need to contact salesforce for same .**

Check the documentation on the same here in [SOAP API GUIDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountownersharingrule.htm) .You will see for Account we have **AccountOwnerSharingRule** Object .

Comment: Thank you Mohit. I have a follow question how to view this object in workbench because I'm getting an error invalid sobject.

Comment: To enable the object you will need to contact salesforce support first .

Comment: Thank you for information. Suppose if we want to delete all of the manually defined sharing rule for the account object . Could you please suggest me a best practice?

Comment: You will need to use destructive XML for deletion .I would recommend to explore that option